# Can't build android app in command line while succ in studio

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I have most recent **Android Studio Hedgehog | 2023.1.1 Patch 2** for this date. Created empty activity project. Tried both kotlin dsl and groovy dsl.
Then can build it with build studio's command. But can't run any gradlew task. Only `./gradlew --version` works and prints following:

> ### ------------------------------------------------------------ Gradle 8.2
>
> Build time:   2023-06-30 18:02:30 UTC Revision:
> 5f4a070a62a31a17438ac998c2b849f4f6892877
>
> Kotlin:       1.8.20 Groovy:       3.0.17 Ant:          Apache Ant(TM)
> version 1.10.13 compiled on January 4 2023 JVM:          1.8.0_382
> (Amazon.com Inc. 25.382-b05) OS:           Mac OS X 14.3.1 aarch64

In **gradle-wrapper.properties** i have `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.2-bin.zip`.
In *Android studio settings / Build / Build tools / Gradle* i have *Gradle JDK* setting set to **GRADLE_LOCAL_JAVA_HOME (jbr 17.0.7)**.
I read some related SO-posts and have no idea what is going on. Every gradlew call ends up with this:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
>A problem occurred configuring root project 'GradleTest2'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.

> Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.2.

> Required by: project :
> com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:8.2.2

> No matching variant of com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.2 was found. The consumer was configured to find a library for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '8.2' but:
          - Variant 'apiElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.2 declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during compile-time, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.2')
          - Variant 'javadocElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.2 declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.2')
          - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.2 declares a library for use during runtime, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component, compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.2')
          - Variant 'sourcesElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.2 declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.2')

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 391ms
mjollneer@IBMPC GradleTest % ./gradlew      

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

**UPD 1.**
System JAVA_HOME currently set to

```
/Users/mjollneer/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/corretto-1.8.0_382/Contents/Home
```

because when i. set it to jbr-17 like this

```
/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home
```

gradlew calls ends up with this

```
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory
```

**UPD 2.**
Project initially created with this version:

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
}
```

But when i change all 3 consts to 11 or 17 - everything remeains the same (ok from studio and fail in command line).

Comment: Could you try updating your compile java version and source java version to 17?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was JAVA_HOME variabe. Mac's default and one from Android Studio internal settings both seems to be not enough.
I just downloaded last from [Oracle](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/jdk17-archive-downloads.html), check JAVA_HOME was updated (`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.jdk/Contents/Home` in my case) and thats all =/